# Why is my for loop not working in my JSON function?

Tags: javascript, json, loops, for-loop

Hey Guys im new at coding and working right now on a Twitch Viewer. (FreeCodeCamp)

Im able to get information from the JSON file and show it through my html code.
But my problem is that i cant get the names from my "gamer" array.

Why is the for loop not working in the json function?

Thank you very much for your help!

```js
var gamer = ["OgamingSC2","ESL_SC2"];

for(i=0;i<(2);i++){
  
$.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'+gamer[i]+'/?callback=?', function(json) {
  $('.list').append("<b>Name: " + gamer[i] + "</b><br>");
  var logo = json.stream.channel.logo;
  
  $('.list').append("Game: " + json.stream.channel.game + "<br>");
  $('.list').append("Status: " + json.stream.channel.status + "<br>");
  $('.list').append("Logo: " + "<img src=" + logo + ">" + "<br><br><br>");
  console.log(json);
});}
```

```css
img {
  width: 5em;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> </head>
<body>
  <b>Twitch.tv JSON API</b> </br>
<div class="list"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: use `gamer[i].name`

Comment: because `$.json` is asynchronous, and `i` is not what you think it is once you hit the `$.json` callback ... @A.J `i` will still be wrong :p

Comment: @JaromandaX : yeah I missed it. *embarrassing*

Comment: @A.J - you forgot to read the code asynchronously :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: @aisen have added a working code snippet here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39137979/1409180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is the `$.getJson` is an asynchronous call, which means that it will execute only after all of the sync operations are executed. So, the `for` loop runs twice, and two `getJSON` callback functions are added to the function stack.

Now as Javascript has lexical or functional scope, the variable `i` lives on in the global scope as `2` (as the final `i++` also has executed).

Next, the callback functions are executed one by one off of the function stack. But alas, your variable `i` is now 2! Now the callback functions would only see `gamer[2]` which doesn't exist and this throws an `undefined`

If you add a `console.log(i)` to your $.getJSON, you'll see that it outputs only `2` two times.

Why don't you try this:

```js
    var gamer = ["OgamingSC2","ESL_SC2"];
    gamer.map(function(gamer) {
      loopIt(gamer);
    });

  function loopIt(gamer) {
    
 
 $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'+gamer+'/?callback=?', function(json) {
      $('.list').append("<b>Name: " + gamer + "</b><br>");
      var logo = json.stream.channel.logo;
      
      $('.list').append("Game: " + json.stream.channel.game + "<br>");
      $('.list').append("Status: " + json.stream.channel.status + "<br>");
      $('.list').append("Logo: " + "<img src=" + logo + ">" + "<br><br><br>");
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> </head>
<body>
  <b>Twitch.tv JSON API</b> </br>
<div class="list"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your really deep explanation! Now i understand whats happening! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

i think it json gives nothing because you put `callback=?` 
when you pass ? in call back variable it take value with ? and gives nothing.
so just put `callback=` .dont give any values and try again. and just alert json variable in function. you will know value is coming or not. i dont found nothing wrong with loop and json link.

Answer (score 0):

For this types of server call in for loop , you can use custom loop.

Like this, https://jsfiddle.net/s8eLhxpx/

```
    var gamer = ["OgamingSC2","ESL_SC2"];

     var initCounter = 0;
     callServerData()

     function callServerData(){
        $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'+gamer[ initCounter ]+'/?callback=?', function(json) {
    $('.list').append("<b>Name: " + gamer[ initCounter ] + "</b><br>");
    var logo = json.stream.channel.logo;

     $('.list').append("Game: " + json.stream.channel.game + "<br>");
     $('.list').append("Status: " + json.stream.channel.status + "<br>");
     $('.list').append("Logo: " + "<img src=" + logo + ">" + "<br><br><br>");
      console.log(json);
      initCounter++
      if(initCounter < gamer.length){

        callServerData();
     }

});
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me a lot!

Comment: for loop not wait for server response , hence you get undefined.